# The PHP linked to this form isn't submitting entries to my database

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I have a form on a website I'm working on which needs to submit information to a MySQL database. I'm primarily a web designer, and PHP is somewhat new to me. I've written this PHP code as the action for my HTML form, which is below:

```php
<?php 
//only process if $_POST isn't empty

if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ){

//connect to mysql
$mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname' );

//check connection
if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
}

//insert data
$sql = ("
INSERT INTO `table` (`ID`, `u_fname`, `u_lname`, `u_email`) 
VALUES (NULL, '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['u_fname'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['u_lname'])}', {$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['u_email'])}')");

$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

//print response from sql
if ( $insert ) {
    echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";   
}
else {
    die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
}

//close connection
$mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

The relevant HTML form is here:

```html
<div class="form-container">
    <form action="signupform.php" method="post" class="isubmit" name="signup" onsubmit="swal({
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'Thanks!',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1500
                })">
        <input required type="text" name="u_fname" class="first-name" placeholder="First Name">

        <input required type="text" name="u_lname" class="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">

        <input required type="text" name="u_email" class="email" placeholder="Email">

        <button class="isubmit submit-text" type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The HTML and PHP files are separate but in the same directory. I'm aware the PHP needs to be made more secure to avoid injection, but that is not my issue. The issue is that when the submit button is pressed, the PHP does not send the entries to my database. The database remains unchanged, and what I need is for the information from the form fields to populate the database table when the user hits the submit button on the HTML form. Any help with my code or suggestions of a better method would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if `ID` is your primary key and auto_increment then you need to omit it from your insert. Are you getting any errors and do you have `display_errors` turned on?

Comment: @prodigitalson not necessary, setting it to NULL will make MySQL use the auto increment value. The problem here is that it's not possible to use `$mysqli->real_escape_string()` in that way inside a string. It needs to be outside the string, although a prepared statement would be a better way to go.

Comment: @rickdenhaan you're right. I've removed the real escape strings, and I'll look into using prepared statements instead. Thanks.

Comment: Do you compulsorily want to use this mysq l_real_escape_string method? Or any good insert will do? Anyone, i will get it for you need to be sure what you feel works best for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the mysqli_real_escape_string from your string in your query and set a variable to equal your post value.  Your 'id' also needs to be removed from the insert as the ID in your database should be an auto increment. Added in an error validation and prepared statement to help prevent sql injection.

```
//insert data
<?php 
    if(!empty($_POST)) {          
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            //connect to mysql
            $mysqli = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname' );

            //check connection
            if (!$mysqli) {
                die( 'Connect Error: ' . mysqli_error());
            }

            $u_fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['u_fname']);
            $u_lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['u_lname']);
            $u_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['u_email']);
            //VALIDATION ARRAY
            $error = [
                "u_fname"=> '',
                "u_lname"=> '',
                "u_email"=> ''
            ];

            if($u_fname == '') {
                $error['u_fname'] = "Please Enter Your First Name";
            }

            if($u_lname == '') {
                $error['u_fname'] = "Please Enter Your Last Name";
            }

            if($u_email == '') {
                $error['u_fname'] = "Please Enter Your Email";
            }
            else {
                //IF NO ERRORS INSERT DATA    
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `table` (`u_fname`, `u_lname`, `u_email`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $u_fname, $u_lname, $u_email);

                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                //print response from sql
                if ($stmt ) {
                    echo "Success!";   
                }
                else {
                    die("Error" . mysqli_error());
                }
                //close connection
                mysqli_close($mysqli);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

And for the Form

```
<div class="form-container">
    <form action="signupform.php" method="post" class="isubmit" name="signup">
        <input required type="text" name="u_fname" class="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
        <span><?php echo isset($error['u_fname']) ? $error['u_fname'] : ''?></span>
        <input required type="text" name="u_lname" class="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
        <span><?php echo isset($error['u_lname']) ? $error['u_lname'] : ''?></span>
        <input required type="text" name="u_email" class="email" placeholder="Email">
        <span><?php echo isset($error['u_email']) ? $error['u_email'] : ''?></span>
        <button class="isubmit submit-text" type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jpegzilla, if this answer worked for you, could you please accept it?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, work was a bit hectic and this slipped my mind the past few days. Unfortunately, this is still not working, and I'm not sure why. I'm not seeing any errors from mysql, and there are certainly no errors in the code. I genuinely don't understand what the problems are here, but thank you for your help so far, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Your <button> doesn't have a name associated with it.    <button class="isubmit submit-text" type="submit">submit</button>.  It should be <button class="isubmit submit-text" type="submit" name='submit'>submit</button>

Comment: Check my edits on the previous answer. Let me know if it works for you.  It was missing a $_POST['submit'] and also a name attribute in the button element, so even though you were clicking the button, the form wasn't being submitted to anything.

Comment: I updated this to be all procedural PHP as I am not familiar enough with OOP, but also added the code to execute via prepared statement for security.

Comment: I actually didn't know about the necessity of the <button> name attribute. Thanks so much again, this is so helpful. Unfortunately, it's still not working. I'm not sure what the issue is - I think it may be a credentials issue. Again, thanks so much for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is you're just not getting a connection to your database. Run an if statement to check if you have a connection. If($mysqli) echo connected.   I'm on my phone now and it won't let put in the proper brackets for this.

Comment: The connection appears to be fine. The last thing I can think of is this: should my index file be index.php or should I keep it as index.html? I'm actually not sure. If that's not it, I'll just keep researching.

Comment: it has to be index.php.  If its set to index.html, it wont run any php scripts that you have, especially if this script and form are on your index page.

Comment: Ok. Only the form is within index.html. The form is in a seperate file.

Comment: index.html will be fine as long as no php is performed on that page.  I made an edit to the above code.  I forgot to put the $mysqli inside the mysqli_real_escape_string and the mysqli_prepare functions.  Each of those require two paramaters; the connection is the first parameter.  I just created a test database on my local server and ran the php code above that I provided with that html form and it worked just fine.  However I ran the php code and html form on my index.php page, but it should work for you since the action is set.